# ¿Como usar correctamente SHORTHAND con la propiedad BACKGROUND?

Tags: css, css3

he intentado optimizar mi código CSS mediante el uso de **shorthand**, específicamente con la propiedad **background**, el problema se dá cuando quiero incorporar la propiedad background-size en el shorthand. por favor agradecería su ayuda ya que anduve averiguando y no logré dar con la solución, no sé si tenga mucho que ver el orden en la que van los valores dentro del shorthand.

Este es el HTML

```
<p><a href="mailto:jean@dominio.com">JEAN LEON: Director Comercial.</a></p>
<p><a href="mailto:shey@dominio.com">SHEYLA RIOS: Jefa de Ventas.</a></p>
```

Aquí el código extendido sin usar shorthand (validada por la W3C):

```
a[href^="mailto"] {
background: url("../imagenes/mail.png") left center no-repeat;
background-size: 1.5em;
padding-left: 40px;}
```

https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando Shorthand devuelve Error.

```
a[href^="mailto"] {
background: url("../imagenes/mail.png") 1.5em left center no-repeat;
padding-left: 40px;}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actualemente la propiedad [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background) acepta los siguientes valores:

> #### Sintaxis:
>
> background: [[`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) || [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) || [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) || [`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) || [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)]  |  inherit ;

A partir de `CSS3`, se ha propuesto agregar las propiedades `background-size, background-origin y background-clip`. [Aquí se puede encontrar el borrador](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background)

La propiedad `background-size`, aún no es un valor **válido** que deba establecerse usando el atajo `background`. Es decir, se puede establecer, va a funcionar (*en los navegadores nuevos*) pero aún no es estándar, por eso no es válido.

---

#### Referencias:

[MDN - CSS > Background > Specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#Specifications)